# Regex to extract content

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I do not know how to use regex in c#. I'm confused.
Here is the URL where i want to exact the id:

https://j-ec.static.com/images/385/**3858715**.jpg

I just want to get the bolded number.

The regex I try to use is:

```
Match thumb_id = Regex.Match(url, @"\/(?)\.jpg");
```

What's wrong?

Any help?

Comment: `?` matches zero or one of what precedes it. In your regex, nothing precedes it. You don't say exactly what you want to match, but it's probably one or more digits: `@"\/([0-9]+)\.jpg")`

Comment: How about `[0-9]+(?=.jpg)`? When you are new to regex, I recommend you regexstorm.net, where you can easily experiment with regex expressions and test them on your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an url. You don't need regex for this.

```
var url = "https://j-ec.static.com/images/385/3858715.jpg";

var id = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead :

```
Match thumb_id = Regex.Match(url, "http://(\\S+?)\\.(jpg)");
```

So you have :

```
  foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, "http://(\\S+?)\\.(jpg)"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it without Regex:

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
```